# Not getting response on live server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying this code on my live server but I don't get response for my request, but when I paste the same code to http://jsfiddle.net it works perfectly. Is there something I need to install to my server or is the code broken? (my server http://dankbut.biz/lolapi/)

```
function summonerLookUp() {
var SUMMONER_NAME = "";
SUMMONER_NAME = $("#userName").val();

var API_KEY = "";
API_KEY = $("#theKey").val();

if (SUMMONER_NAME !== "") {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + SUMMONER_NAME + '?api_key=' + API_KEY,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {

        },
        success: function (json) {
            var SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SUMMONER_NAME.replace(" ", "");

            SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES = SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES.toLowerCase().trim();

            summonerLevel = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].summonerLevel;
            summonerID = json[SUMMONER_NAME_NOSPACES].id;

            document.getElementById("sLevel").innerHTML = summonerLevel;
            document.getElementById("sID").innerHTML = summonerID;

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert("error getting Summoner data!");
        }
    });
} else {}
}
```

Comment: where do you call the function from?

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's JavaScript console?

Comment: error "ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: So you don't have jQuery initialized on the moment of initialization of script. Have you got it at all?

Comment: No, I don't think so. I'm beginner with these things.